# How to remove Quarantine from file permissions in OS X

Tags: macos, file-permissions, osx-mountain-lion

I downloaded a `.pem` file and my Mac OS X (10.8.2) added an `@` sign at the end of the file permissions. This is causing file permission issues.

I can't seem to remove the quarantine flag. I even tried the command

```
xattr -d <filename>.pem
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First, use `ls -l@` to see what extended attributes are attached to the file. Normally, a downloaded file will have xattrs named "com.apple.quarantine" and maybe "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms". To remove them, you can delete them individually with e.g. `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine filename.pem`, or clear all xattrs with `xattr -c filename.pem`

Comment: And to expand upon this, to unquarantine an entire directory, `xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine directory`.